# Browser behavior on history back and forward

Tags: browser, browser-history

I would like to understand a particular browser behavior in regard to the back and forward buttons. I always believed that in a "traditional" navigation, clicking the back and forward buttons caused the page to reload, unless we were just changing the hash on the same page (can't recall now if there are other obvious exceptions).

Lately I've observed a behavior that shattered those believes: changing page caused the browser to save a "snapshot" of the last state the page was before navigating away, so whenever I pressed the back button it would take me to the exact moment I navigated away.

While this can be a very useful behavior the problem is that this way I'm showing the user potentially outdated data.

Same behavior happens if I press the forward button: I will land to the next page I visited at the exact state it was when I pressed the back button.

So I spent a little time and started testing different browsers and different domains using the same application and applying the same conditions to come to the following result:

- **Chrome 102**: this behavior happened when navigating on a public domain on the Internet with `Dev Tools` closed. Whenever I tried it in localhost or with `Dev Tools` open the reloading happened.
- **Safari 15**: this behavior happened always, didn't matter wether I was on localhost or I had `Dev Tools` open.
- **Opera 88**: this behavior happened when navigating on a public domain on the Internet regardless the presence of Dev Tools. When navigating on localhost it reloaded the pages.
- **Firefox 101** and **Edge 102** didn't exhibit this behavior, they simply reloaded the pages when navigating.

Is there any explanation or documentation for this difference of behavior? I tried to search it but nothing meaningful came out, perhaps I'm not using the right words.

### Update

I checked headers coming from the responses but I think they're not relevant:

These are localhost's

```
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2022 08:58:01 GMT
ETag: W/"57cf-+fmYAdB1w1b8e3hCMCGT2IIRFCg"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

For the public domains relevant headers are

```
cache-control: max-age=0
date: Thu, 23 Jun 2022 10:10:23 GMT
expires: Thu, 23 Jun 2022 10:10:23 GMT
```

Which tell the browser to not cache the page, and that's why I didn't add them in the original question.

Comment: Have you first of all checked what caching related response headers these documents were served with ...?

Comment: Yes, I'll update the question with my reasoning